# vue-typed-js plugin not worked on static site nux

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

In my nuxt.js project I am using a component from a Vue library called [vue-typed-js](https://github.com/Orlandster/vue-typed-js#installation)

I import the library as a plugin in this way (as advised by the author):

/plugins/vue-typed.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueTypedJs from 'vue-typed-js'

Vue.use(VueTypedJs)
```

/nuxt.config.js

```js
plugins: ['~plugins/vue-typed']
```

My problem is that the component is not rendered when I serve the app generated with

```
nuxt generate
```

i tried to do like this:

```
{ src: '~plugins/vue-typed', mode:  'client' }
```

and I still see in my browser dev tools

```js
  <vue-typed-js :strings="['Typing text']" :cursorChar="'_'" :startDelay="1000">
    <span class="typing"></span>
  </vue-typed-js>
```

and when i did that

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import { VueTypedJs } from 'vue-typed-js/dist/vue-typed-js.common';
import 'vue-typed-js/dist/vue-typed-js.css'

Vue.component('vue-typed-js',VueTypedJs)
```

it got better but still doesn't work

```js
<div class="typed-element"><span class="typing"></span></div>
  <span class="typing"></span>
<div class="typed-element" ><span class="typing"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
plugins: ['~plugins/vue-typed']
```

Try this

```
plugins: ['@/plugins/vue-typed']
```